# How to use Max, Vlookup, and Match together

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use max, Vlookup, and match together? As of now my formula is using max and Vlookup together, however I get an error each time I try to add match to it.

I have a different sheet for each month of the year. In a new sheet that reviews all of the months I'm trying to search for a specific phrase ($D94) throughout all of the sheets (C56:AY70), and find the highest value in column 49 (AY). I've accomplished this and the formula works, however now I want the highest value to match the text one cell to the right (column 50,AZ ).

```html
=MAX
(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D94,JANUARY!C56:AY70,49, FALSE),"0"),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D94,FEBRUARY!C56:AY70,49, FALSE),"0"),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D94,MARCH!C56:AY70,49)))
```

Comment: look into MAXIFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this in sheets:

```
=QUERY({{January!C56:AZ70};
{February!C56:AZ70};
{March!C56:AZ70}},
"Select Col50 Where Col1='"&D94&"' ORDER BY Col49 DESC limit 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, to get the max value in column `AY` on each sheet, along with the value in the adjacent cell, together with the sheet name, use this pattern:

```
=byrow( 
  { "JANUARY"; "FEBRUARY"; "MARCH" }, 
  lambda( 
    sheetName, 
    { 
      sheetName, 
      query( 
        indirect(sheetName & "!C56:AZ70"), 
        "select AY, AZ 
         where C = '" & D94 & "' 
         order by AY desc limit 1", 
        0 
      ) 
    } 
  ) 
)
```

In the event cell `D94` or column `C` does not always contain a text string, use `filter()`, like this:

```
=byrow( 
  { "JANUARY"; "FEBRUARY"; "MARCH" }, 
  lambda( 
    sheetName, 
    { 
      sheetName, 
      query( 
        filter( indirect(sheetName & "!AY56:AZ70"), D94 = indirect(sheetName & "!C56:C70") ), 
        "order by Col2 desc limit 1", 0 
      ) 
    } 
  ) 
)
```

To get the highest value in the result table, use `sortn()`.